# How to find out min api level of each included library

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a lot of libraries included into the project (Android Studio 2.0 Preview 4). I want to find out min Android SDK level of each of them. Is it possible without googling info about every library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the library in source form (e.g., as a library module in your project), look at its manifest.

If you have the library in AAR form, that's just a ZIP file, so look inside it and examine its manifest, or use the technique in the next paragraph.

If you have the library as an AAR but via an artifact from a repository, the "exploded AAR" will be in your `build/` output. For an `app` module, look in `app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/` for those AARs. There will be subdirectories based on group ID, artifact ID, and version. In there, you will find the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Even if the original library's source had the `minSdkVersion` in its `build.gradle`, the generated `AndroidManifest.xml` in the AAR (and in `exploded-aar/`) should have the `minSdkVersion` in there.

If the library is just a JAR, you're stuck with reading documentation, as the toolchain has no knowledge of a minimum SDK and cannot enforce it.