# App is not running on Android 4.4 and 5.1

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, apk

My application works on Android 6 and above, but I tested it on Android 4.4 and 5.1 it is installed normally but when running it crushes

this is my build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gogrocer.tcc"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.2"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        dexOptions {
            preDexLibraries = false
        }
        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
            // but continue the build even when errors are found:
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/godel-release/godel/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion,GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.+'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'

    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.2.1'
    implementation files('libs/PGSDK_v1.0.jar')
    implementation 'com.github.franmontiel:LocaleChanger:0.9.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.shamanland:fonticon:0.1.8'
    implementation('com.nispok:snackbar:2.11.+') {
        // exclusion is not necessary, but generally a good idea.
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
    implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.46'
    implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.2'

    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
    implementation files('libs/httpmime-4.2.5-sources.jar')

}
// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            Device compatibility overview
```

Android is designed to run on many different types of devices, from phones to tablets and televisions. As a developer, the range of devices provides a huge potential audience for your app. In order for your app to be successful on all these devices, it should tolerate some feature variability and provide a flexible user interface that adapts to different screen configurations.

Comment: Instead of the last paragraph, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58043918/edit) your post with the error encountered and what you've tried to debug the problem.

Comment: @MorrisonChang apk not compatible withe android 4.4 and 5.1,  i need to be

Comment: See: [How to find out min api level of each included library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34373051/295004) and find out which one(s) aren't supported. And confirm that you've setup [Multidex support below 5.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-pre-l)

Comment: Can we have the crash report so we can have better understanding what happened.

Comment: @Eldhopj the error "Unfortunately,GoGrocer has stopped"

Comment: Farhat, please connect the device and run the app and provide us the logcat crash log.

Comment: [tag:CRUSH] is an acronym for Controlled Replication Under Scalable Hashing. It is the algorithm that drives the Ceph object storage environment.  it doesn't seem to apply here.  For the record, it's "Crash", not "Crush"

Answer (score 0):

The device your app can run on, depends on the minimum API level you selected when creating the project. For your app to run on lower android versions, you need to select a low API (I usually go with API 19 : android 4.4) when creating your project

Answer (score 0):

edit your minSdkVersion to 15 instead of 19

Answer (score -1):

That was because you wanted it to work  for android 6.0 and above in your code

Comment: I need the solution

Answer (score -1):

When setting I believe you set its configuration for higher versions. check if this is the case

Comment: this is more of a comment than an answer

Comment: I need the solution